# Favicon on a executable jar file

Tags: java, favicon

we have a maven project which have a favicon when we run application on Eclipse or on IntelliJ but the .jar doesn't have it. Neverthless, when i unzip jar file there are favicon in the correct location. So why i can't have it on my .jar

This is our code for the favicon.

```html
public class MainApp extends Application {

 private Stage primaryStage;
 private BorderPane rootLayout;
 private MainController mainController;

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
  this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
  this.primaryStage.setTitle("Projet Informatique utilisant l'API Twitter");
  this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:src/main/resources/images/favicon.png"));
```

Comment: when you open the jar, is there a folder structure like `src/main/resources`? Because in a jar file built with maven, there shouldnt be.

Comment: No there is only the folder images, do you think i need to change it by the folder in the jar ?

Comment: Yes I need to use this path, thank you can we put a subject to solved subject ?